# Wrong result on equation

Tags: c#, equation

I have this equation: **1 - (1 + 0.001) <sup>-48</sup>**
where the result should be: **0.379**

But in my code this happens:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     double test = Math.Pow((1 - (1 + 0.001)), -48);
     Console.WriteLine("" + test);
}
```

> Result: 1,00000000000529E+144

And this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double test = Math.Pow(-48, (1 - (1 + 0.001)));
    Console.WriteLine("" + test);
}
```

> Result: Nan

What is the correct way to compute this operation?

Comment: The code has 0.001, the question states 0.01 Which one is right?

Comment: Typo? `1 - Math.Pow(1 + 0.01, -48);`

Comment: if you want to get 0.379 then you should use 0.01, not 0.001...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

`double test = 1 - Math.Pow((1 + 0.01), -48);`

Comment: Sure.. I don't know why it gets down-voted... it's clear, and shows an attempt to solve...